# How to refresh gridster widget on button-click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, widget, refresh, gridster

I have created 3 gridster widget with 2 buttons inside widget for remove widget and for refresh widget.
    Removing of widget is done as gridster have inbuilt remove_widget function but how do i refresh the content inside the widget.
    I have one button at the top for adding widget so in that also i want the refresh widget button.

// Javascript Code//
    Script File

```
 $(function () {
        $(".gridster ul").gridster({

            widget_margins: [10, 10],
            widget_base_dimensions: [140, 140],
            animate: true,

        })

    }).data('gridster');

    $(document).on("click", ".gridster .delete-button", function () {
        var gridster = $(".gridster ul").gridster().data('gridster');
        gridster.remove_widget($(this).parent());
    });


    $(document).on("click", ".add-small", function () {
        var gridster = $(".gridster ul").gridster().data('gridster');
        gridster.add_widget('<li class=""><a href="#" class="delete-button" style="float:right;"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a><a href="#" class="refresh" style="float: right;"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i></a><h3>Title</h3><div class="content"><h3>3</h3></div></li>', 1, 1, 1, 1);
    });

Thanks in advance
```

Comment: Could you please rephrase this question to make it more readable, and please post the code you have so far?

Comment: Create the jsfiddle of your code first. http://jsfiddle.net